Restore all CMD commands (or windows commands)
I was messing with the environment variables and PATH, etc and i think i got rid of a bunch of terminal commands by accident (nodeJs commands, python, etc) even the windows ones.
So i cant run commands like bcedit, powershell and who knows what else because cmd doesn't recognize them.
And i was wondering if there was a way to restore it, maybe like a setting in the enviroment variables or similar.
Sorry if my english isn't clear.

Did you modify the user variable or system variable?
